# Stop URLRewrite check after slash

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Below is my current Apache configuration in .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^(user)($|/) - [L]

RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+) /user_/index.php?u=$1 [L]
```

I want to rewrite `www.mydomain.com/user/test` to `www.mydomain.com/user_/index.php?u=test`

But, I don't want to rewrite anything if it is only `www.mydomain.com/user` or `www.mydomain.com/user/` where `user` is a directory in my server.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
  AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
    Options -Indexes
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /?user/(.*)$
    RewriteRule /?user/(.*)$  user_/index.php?u=$1 [QSA,L]
```

here:
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /?user/(.*)$`  for check condition

Comment: it's working but when i enter `www.mydomain.com/user/test/` it does not work. 
there's a slash at the end of the url

Comment: @Bhupendra Pandey    try to by change from `/?user/(.*)$` to `/?user/([^/]+)/?$`  . this may work

Answer (score 0):

You need to use quantifier `.+` to make sure you don't match `/user` or `/user/` like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^user/(.+)$ user_/index.php?u=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: **didn't work** like comments don't help anyone. Q0. What URL are you entering in your browser? Q1. Is this the only .htaccess or do you have another? Q2. Is this the only code in this .htaccess? If you have some other code then please post it in question? Q3. What is full path of above .htaccess?

Comment: I tried inputting `localhost/user/test/` and it didn't work. but `localhost/user/test` is working fine

Comment: I had asked so many questions in my comment. Spend some time in answering them. Is `/user/test/` a real directory? Also where is this .htaccess located?